# Can 'false' match some string in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `created_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '创建时间',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=41 ;
```

and some data in this table:

```
(38, '395d5feaf28df01aafe0781a7f34acbe', 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"2";s:8:"username";s:7:"wanmeng";s:12:"created_time";s:19:"2011-11-18 19:37:33";}', '2011-12-03 14:14:35'),
(39, '0e0ca06ed9ad86937f190eb9544ac935', 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:8:"username";s:6:"delphi";s:12:"created_time";s:19:"2011-11-18 13:29:40";}', '2011-12-03 14:28:36'),
(31, '3cba76b97cf123009632bdaa5a306385', 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:8:"username";s:6:"delphi";s:12:"created_time";s:19:"2011-11-18 13:29:40";}', '2011-12-02 15:50:21'),
(30, 'fa356333dd3ee8f1b18b8bf0a827e34c', 'a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:8:"username";s:6:"delphi";s:12:"created_time";s:19:"2011-11-18 13:29:40";}', '2011-12-01 15:32:47')
```

When I execute the query: SELECT * FROM `session` WHERE token = false , I expect no result returned, but the mysql returns the results:

```
39  0e0ca06ed9ad86937f190eb9544ac935    a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:8:"username";s:6:"delphi";...   2011-12-03 22:28:36
30  fa356333dd3ee8f1b18b8bf0a827e34c    a:3:{s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:8:"username";s:6:"delphi";...   2011-12-01 23:32:47
```

It seems like the boolean value 'false' can match some varchar, but is there any relation between 'fa356333dd3ee8f1b18b8bf0a827e34c' and 'false', why is it so?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38dd9e/2 example of vulnerability

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MYSQL, [FALSE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/boolean-literals.html) is not a boolean value, it's an integer, more specifically zero. In fact, MySQL does not have boolean column types (it has `BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` but they're mere aliases for `TINYINT`). So your query is a synonym for:

```
SELECT * FROM session WHERE token = 0
```

Since `token` is a VARCHAR, MySQL needs to convert your strings to number. Run this query and you'll get an idea about the rules:

```
SELECT
    0 + "0001",
    0 + "123abc",
    0 + "abc123"
```

As a result, `fa356333dd3ee8f1b18b8bf0a827e34c` casts to `0` because it starts with a letter, thus the match.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare a boolean with a varchar, MySQL has to do some implicit type conversion. MySQL casts the varchar value to a boolean, checking only the first character.

If the character is a character or number 0, then the string is evaluated to 0, thus False.
If the character is a number different than 0, then the string is evaluted to 1, thus True (and not appearing in your result set)

The only thing to do is not to compare a string with a boolean, because it makes no sense.

Comment: The information about number parsing from strings is correct but there aren't any booleans involved here. MySQL does not even have boolean column types.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Yes, you are right, but it is not important to grasp the concept here. There's a value casted to another in order to compare them, whether it is a boolean or an integer is not important. The clarification is probably necessary, though, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you're not testing `token is null` or `token like ''`?  Comparing a varchar to false is a bad idea regardless of whether the DB will catch your mistake or not... a varchar is never false, and false doesn't equal null.

Comment: I'm doing a program with CodeIgniter and I have a method for get the token from http get, like get("token"), and if the "token" is not in the $_GET, it will return false. I simply pass the value to my model method to fetch the session which token equal the passed token, then I found when the token is false, mysql also return some rows for me. I have changed my query to "token = null", but I wondering why it returns that, so I post the question. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: actually, if I recall correctly "token = null" won't work either! I think you can only compare null to "is" as in... "token is null". I won't swear to this, but that's my recollection.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation... so..

DelphiQin, you said in a comment that you are passing the result of the CI "get()" method to the query parameter. I've been there and I solved by just casting the variable to string before passing to the query:

```
(string)$my_var
```

This way, it will use '' (empty string) instead of boolean false.

I hope it helps people with the same problem.