# Insert a PHP false into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, data-conversion

My MySQL table contains a tinyint(1) value that i use to store a true or false value.

I have the following PHP variables:

```
$name = '';
$description = '';
$active = true;
```

Now my SQL query is as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT into my_table (my_name, my_description, active) VALUES ('$name', '$description', $active) ";
```

This will only work if my value for $active is true. As soon as the active variable is false, php will insert an empty string, instead of a 0 and thus the query will fail.

What is the best method to use false in such a query?

Should i manually convert the false to a '0' string?
Is it better use stings on the PHP side right away? in other words declare: $active = '1';
or can i somehow get PHP to always convert false to a '0' string?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can 'false' match some string in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369379/can-false-match-some-string-in-mysql)

Comment: You should really use the data type `bit(1)` in your database. This will only allow `0` (false) and `1` (true) inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your values should be escaped using mysql_real_escape_string or mysqli_real_escape_string or other method suitable for your database connection to avoid sql injection then for your specific question regarding false you may do something like that:

```
$query = "INSERT into my_table (my_name, my_description, active) VALUES ('$name', '$description', ".($active?1:0) .")";
```

or casting $active to int should do the work too:

```
$query = "INSERT into my_table (my_name, my_description, active) VALUES ('$name', '$description', ".((int) $active)).")";
```

Comment: Thanks. I have simplified this question a lot from my actual code. All strings are escaped properly :-) I was hoping for a solution without first having to convert my datatype, but I guess this is not possible.

Comment: To avoid double data-type conversion I have used $bool?'1':'0' as your first example showed but with strings returned instead of integers.

Answer (score 6):

Convert your variable to int:

```
intval($active)
```

Answer (score 0):

use a mysql_real_escape_string function...

```
$query = "INSERT into my_table (my_name, my_description, active) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)."', ".mysql_real_escape_string (((int) $active))).")";
```

Comment: Thanks PHP, for turning a single bit into `mysql_real_escape_string (((int) $active)))`